# specialized extension of Dictionary

Tags: swift, generics

How can I declare an extension that will work only for a particular type?

I tried this:

```
extension Dictionary where
    Key : CustomStringConvertible,
    Value: CustomStringConvertible
{
    func queryString() -> String {
        var paramArray = Array<String>()
        for (key, value) in self {
            paramArray.append("\(key.description)=\(value.description)")
        }
        return "&".join(paramArray)
    }
}
```

And it compiles fine. But when I try to use it

```
var d = Dictionary<String, String>()
var q = d.queryString() // <-- ERROR
```

I get the error:

> Cannot invoke 'queryString' with no arguments

What is wrong here? I want to be able to call `queryString` on a Dictionary but only when it is `Dictionary<String, String>`

Any help is highly appreciated.

### Edit

As @jtbandes said, `String` does not conform to `CustomStringConvertible`. [CustomStringConvertible Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CustomStringConvertible_Protocol/index.html) suggests to use `String()` constructor to get a string rather than using the protocol as a constrain.

> NOTE: String(instance) will work for an instance of any type, returning its description if the instance happens to be CustomStringConvertible. Using CustomStringConvertible as a generic constraint, or accessing a conforming type's description directly, is therefore discouraged.

```
extension Dictionary {
    public func queryString() -> String {
        var paramArray = Array<String>()
        for (key, value) in self {
            paramArray.append("\(String(key))=\(String(value))")
        }
        return "&".join(paramArray)
    }
}
```

### Edit2

This is my final version.

```
extension Dictionary {
    public func queryString() -> String {
        var queryItems = Array<NSURLQueryItem>()
        for (key, value) in self {
            queryItems.append(NSURLQueryItem(name: String(key), value: String(value)))
        }
        let comps = NSURLComponents();
        comps.queryItems = queryItems
        return comps.percentEncodedQuery!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String` is not `CustomStringConvertible`. You can use:

```
extension String: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String { return self }
}
```

Or, I would recommend making your own protocol for this case:

```
protocol QueryStringConvertible {
    var queryStringRepresentation: String { get }
}

extension String: QueryStringConvertible {
    var queryStringRepresentation: String { return self /*probably should escape the string here*/ }
}

extension Dictionary where
    Key : QueryStringConvertible,
    Value : QueryStringConvertible ...
```

But in reality, I think you might want to take a look at [NSURLQueryItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLQueryItem_Class/index.html) and [NSURLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLComponents_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLComponents) :)

Comment: I see. Is there a way to constrain the extension to String type? without declaring a new protocol? or making string to adopt a protocol? Something like `extension Dictionary where Key : String, Value: String { ....`  would be ideal for me

Comment: I want to encode a dictionary of strings into a query string. I think NSURLComponents is for the opposite things.

Comment: Au contraire: `let comps = NSURLComponents(); comps.queryItems = [NSURLQueryItem(name: "foo", value: "bar")]; comps.percentEncodedQuery // returns "foo=bar"`

Comment: Thanks! I found a way to declare it correctly but with NSURLComponents I don't think I need it anyway. Thanks :)

Comment: OK..just think about what happens when your keys or values have `=` or `&` characters in them...

Comment: By "I don't think I need it anyway" I meant I don't need my version since NSURLComponents will do the encoding I was doing (part I was not showing here)